# JMETER Assertion for response not working

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I have my Response assertion updated as shown in screenshot. it work when condition match but when it doesn't match i still get error because response is null. as the request posted is successful

[image]

Comment: can you show an overview of your plan : Tools > Schematic overview or make a screenshot of your plan highlighting the assertion

Answer (score 0):

If you expect particular that request to have [HTTP 404 status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and you want to mark it as successful - just tick `Ignore Status` box and that would be it.

[image]

Also make sure that the assertion is applied only to this sampler(s) it should be applied to, in order words it acts according to the [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) and you need to be aware of these rules.